# How add extra hour to the table showing only timeseries dates

Tags: sql

I have the following table.
Every last Sunday of October the time changes (so for this day extra hour is created during the day). I.E. on 25.04.2020, time shifts 1 hour back at 03:00 (GMT+3), so for that day we have 25 hours. How is it possible that this SQL will also show this extra hour as a duplicate to 25.04.2020 03:00.

The same is for March, however, it shows duplicated values at 04:00 (GMT+3) and ignores 03:00. How is it possible to replace one of two 04:00 with 03:00?

I also noticed that when adding `TO_CHAR(ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:00:00')` (instead of `select ts from ...`), it solves the problem for March, however, if use `TO_CHAR(ts,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:00:00')::timestamp` then the duplicate appears again.

```
SELECT ts  FROM ( 
                SELECT '2020-10-20'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'  AS tm
                UNION
                SELECT '2020-10-30'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'  AS tm
                ) AS t TIMESERIES ts AS '1 Hour' OVER (ORDER BY tm)
ORDER BY ts
```

My output and desired output

[image]

Comment: Don't store raw timestamps as GMT or adjusted for timezone.  Store them as UTC.  UTC doesn't have day-light-savings or other timezone related changes, and so never has duplicates.  UTC is an absolute time, without the possibility of ambiguity or conflict.  Then, depending on you particular database, you can look at adding timezone information if required.  SQL Server, for example, has the following... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I  think the problem not in time zones, as in October all time zones have an extra hour in one day.

Comment: First, not all timezones adjust for daylight savings ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country ).  Second, UTC isn't a timezone ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time ).

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Even if I add `AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Helsinki' ` after my timestamps it will not give the necessary output

Comment: Your data needs to be in UTC ***in the first place***.  If your data is already in `TIME ZONE 'Europe/Helsinki'`, then you have already lost information.  You can't tell if a timestamp of `Sunday, 25 October 2020, 03:01:23` is Before the clocks changed or After the clocks changed.  Do you have Any other information recorded from which you an infer or calculate this?

Comment: I updated the question and now it is in UTC, however, the same results. No, I have only this information with time ranges

Comment: Based on your edits, please update your question to show actual examples which you can and can not cope with...  Read this for more information on why we need example data as well as your description : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: Here's an example of how the data should be stored : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2547cdb7371156330712f4d2cd1343a9  If you have not included in the data the timezone or offset, there is ***now way*** to know if `2020-10-25 03:01:00.0000000` is ***actually*** `2020-10-25 03:01:00.0000000 +03:00` or `2020-10-25 03:01:00.0000000 +02:00` *(you'd just be guessing as to which record to 'correct')*

Comment: A more verbose example... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c3dba0d179e16a242e6176bdb27d5908